# Boto handling S3 key paths with empty folder names

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I have paths in my S3 bucket that, due to buggy code, ended up looking like this:

```
/folder///image.png
```

Yes those are blank folder names. S3 recognizes them and I can view them in my browser just fine.

But when I use boto to try to access them like so:

```
key = Key(bucket)
key.name = "/folder///image.png"
key.exists() [returns False]
```

It truncates the name in the request like so

```
/folder/image.png
```

Removing the duplicate /'s and thus not referencing the proper key.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: folders are just prefixes, so they are not really folder but rather an object named "folder/folder/folder/object.ext"  with a convention followed that if you use '/' then browsers/clients will treat it like a collection and group them to look like a file system.   As a result, I suspect that your object is either called "folder/image.png" or "folder///image.png" and boto is not sure how to handle the extra / and is removing it.   I find it hard to think it is actually empty, but rather a non-printing character.. such as ^M or <CR>.  can you show what results from a .get_all_keys() or similar ?

Answer (score -1):

k.bucket.connection.suppress_consec_slashes = False